# OnMouseOut Fails to fire React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

```
  <div data-layer="02537886-ed86-42d3-8636-2eb14be0f1d6" className="hiThereImEthanaspiringDeveloperAndStudentInSherwoodOregonFluentInC"><span className="hiThereImEthanaspiringDeveloperAndStudentInSherwoodOregonFluentInC-0">Hi there, I'm Ethan.<br /></span><span className="hiThereImEthanaspiringDeveloperAndStudentInSherwoodOregonFluentInC-21">Aspiring developer and student in Sherwood, Oregon. Fluent in C# and C++. Check out my latest classwork and projects.</span></div>
  <div data-layer="7ada00ae-6dad-4f77-ade5-bf2f75c0d775" className="navbar">
     <div data-layer="59cc0bc3-2bf9-4f79-be78-a1ca20e7795e" className="rectangle2"></div>
     <div data-layer="09a61ec3-8712-441c-904c-fc3bbb3b6909" className="component34">
        <div data-layer="4318e043-754b-448e-b68b-4ab40f134b0f" className="contact" onMouseOver={this.changeBackground} onMouseOut={this.resetBackround}>Contact</div>
     </div>
     <Link data-layer="3deeca70-3656-43d9-be1d-40e60e8c9302" className="classwork3bfce124" to='/Classwork'>
     <div data-layer="4eddfb21-ca6f-44bd-9651-ca6034965f18" className="classwork" onMouseOver={this.changeBackground} onMouseOut={this.resetBackround}>Classwork</div>
     </Link>
     <Link data-layer="a905b090-38a3-40ae-9b94-39cabb23994b" className="homeLink" to='/'>
     <div data-layer="3959a03d-437c-4201-b91d-ca43e4d547b5" className="home" onMouseOver={this.changeBackground} onMouseOut={this.resetBackround}>Home</div>
     </Link>
</div>
```

Here is some code from a client's website that will not reset the text color after the mouse leaves the text!

```
constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {

      };
  }
  changeBackground(e) {
    e.target.style.color = 'red';
  }
  resetBackground(e) {
       e.target.style.color = 'white';
    }

  
  handleClick(target) {
    if (this.props.onClick) {
        let name;
        let id;
        let index = -1;
        if (target.search("::") > -1) {
            const varCount = target.split("::").length;
            if (varCount === 2) {
                name = target.split("::")[0];
                id = target.split("::")[1];
            } else if (varCount === 3) {
                name = target.split("::")[0];
                index = parseInt(target.split("::")[1]);
                id = target.split("::")[2];
            }
        } else {
            name = target;
        }
        this.props.onClick({ type: 'button', name: name, index: index, id: id });
    }
  }
```

[image: The Text stays red!]

This image shows how it turns red when the mouse is over it but won't return to white after the mouse leaves. I am trying to make this website have some fancier hover animations. If there is a easier way to make a transition fade in and out then tell me! I just had read this was the easiest way. :( I don't know about that one!

Comment: Can you format the code properly? Wrap your code blocks in ``` rather than using the 8 space indent thing. Then you can just copy it from your code editor and paste it in.

Comment: There is missing JSX in there too. Create a codesandbox.io project. Check this out too: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yeah The issue is it delves into more, let me say confidential stuff right after that code

Comment: @Steve I also updated to show the called functions

Comment: there's no hover logic here, all i see is a click code.

Comment: There are two seperate snips of code

Comment: Read my last comment. Make a minimal example. Do we really need all those `data-layer` attributes in the JSX? There is a ton of `className` attributes that might be applying additional CSS to the elements. We can't see the CSS. Make the question easy for people to answer.

Comment: @Steve I edited again, this is the issue onMouseOut={this.resetBackround}

Comment: You can lead a horse to water, but you can't make it drink.

Comment: Haha you've got a point! Really this is just asking for help on setting up hovering in react

Comment: You want to create something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/mouse-hover-9wlhp?file=/src/App.js) and add it to your question. Currently, the code is incomplete and there is missing CSS which is possibly where the issue is coming from. No one will help you if you don't ask the question properly.

Comment: @Steve Thats exactly what I attempted to implement but it never changed back! Thanks for the help I just will have to go through my code, I've even put a console.log statement in both and the out event never fires

Comment: @3GamersStudios You've spelled `this.resetBackround` wrong. -> `this.resetBackground`